# Django Project: Link in base.html resulting in an error

Tags: django, view, render

I have a link to "Add Album" specified in the base.html in my Django project. **The code is below**

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="{% url 'music:album-add' %}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Add Album
                    </a>
                </li>
```

**When the "Add Album" link is clicked however, it results in an error:**

```
ValueError at /music/album-add/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'album-add'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/album-add/
Django Version: 2.0
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'album-add'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 947
```

**The music/views.py file code is below**

```
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Album

#=============HOME PAGE===================
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    #specify template being used
    template_name='music/index.html' #when we get a list of all albums, plug them into this template
    context_object_name='all_albums' #if you don't use this variable it is automatically just object_list (which is used in index.html)

    #make a query set
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Album.objects.all()


#=============DETAILS VIEW=============== details about one object
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    #what model are we looking at /for
    model=Album
    template_name='music/detail.html'

#===============For the add album form  
class AlbumCreate(CreateView):
    model=Album
    fields=['artist','album_title','genre','album_logo']
    template_name='music/album_form.html'
```

**The urls.py code:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

from . import views #the dot means look at the current directory - look for a module called views

app_name='music'

urlpatterns = [
    #this is matching /music/
     path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
     #when you use a detail view it expects a primary key
     path("<pk>/", views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
     #/music/album/add - dont need to specify pk
     path('album/add/', views.AlbumCreate.as_view(), name="album-add"),
]
```

Can anyone spot the error to fix the problem? I need the "Add Album" link to go to the album_form.html page. music/templates/music/album_form.html (which contains the album_form, including a form template.

Comment: How does your `include` look for the music urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "detail" URL pattern is too general, and is capturing everything - including the string 'album-add'. You should do two things: constrain it to an integer with `"<int:pk>/"`, and/or move it after the album-add pattern.

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I'm still struggling with another question, which is related to the pk, I think.